# How can I get the value from oci_fetch_array and call it by field name

Tags: php, oracle

```
function DBQueryWTable($sql)
{    
  $stid = oci_parse(DBConnect(), $sql);

  oci_execute($stid);

  while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) != false)
  {
    return $row;
  }    

  DBDisconnect();
}
```

I want to retrieve value from this function and load to table by fieldname.

Answer (score 0):

```
$row["columnname"]
```

or

in your query select only one column